# mediaplayer in Visual Basic 2013 ASP.NET web application project doesn't work on Chrome or FireFox

Tags: android, asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome

I need to show media player with PLAY button for user to press.
Works on IE but not Chrome or FireFox.

Needs to be run by the public on any browser (at least Chrome, FF, IE, Safari), and on Windows, Macs, and mobile devices (browsers on iOS and Android).

```
  <object id="MediaPlayer" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
 standby="Loading Windows Media Player..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
    <param name="FileName" VALUE="Company_Video.mp4">
    <param name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
    <param name="autostart" VALUE="false">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="Company_Video.mp4" name="MediaPlayer"
 width="192" height="190" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"> </embed>
 </object>
```

Comment: Because Chrome and FireFox don't support ActiveX objects (they're something that only IE understand). If you want to make it cross-platform I'd try with Flash or BETTER with HTML 5 video tag.

Comment: Flash won't play on iOS.  Look to HTML 5 video tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to 
audio controls 
 and it now works on Chrome, IE, Safari, but still not FireFox.

```
                 <video width="640"  controls="controls" preload="auto">
                        <source src="APPLICANT_VIDEO/<% = job_video_filename %>.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                    <source src="APPLICANT_VIDEO/<% = job_video_filename %>.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>   
                    <source src="APPLICANT_VIDEO/<% = job_video_filename %>.webm" type="video/webm"/>
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
```